# How to save the "Undo History" in GIMP (even though it's not actually possible)?

Tags: gimp

I'm shocked that this isn't done by default:

https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-undo.html

> Even though the **Undo History** is a component of an image, it is **not**
> **saved** when you save the image using GIMP's native XCF format, which
> preserves every other image property. When the image is reopened, it
> will have an empty Undo History.

Others apparently were too (several years ago) and filed a bug report, which is still sort-of open: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/89

Be that as it may, are there any ways to effectively save the "undo history" in GIMP still? E.g., by creating a new layer (if so, with which settings/options?) for every single operation?

---

There is an earlier, related question [gimp: can you save the file with all the undo history?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161529/gimp-can-you-save-the-file-with-all-the-undo-history) which was basically answered in the *negative*; I'm interested in (beginner-friendly) **work-arounds** to still make it work.

Comment: No you can not save undo. This is a fairly typical limitation in most applications. Maintaining undo in a file would blow your image files to really big files. Plus youd have to save in a properitary format that only can be opened by one application. This isnt really suitable for direct data manipulation tools like gimp. So a workaround is to save a copy of image every time you do something.

Comment: The answer is still the same. There is no such feature in GIMP, not even in Adobe Photoshop. It's unlikely ever to happen TBH because it would create huge file sizes, making it ompletely impractical. It's not a bug. You're "shocked"? No, this is the norm for most (if not all) graphics software, and even other software like Word, Excel, etc. Once saved and closed, all undos are lost.

Comment: @BillyKerr MS Office is an interesting analogy: here one can record a VBA macro to store certain edits... why not also in GIMP etc, i.e., to store only the "commands" (or clicks) but not the intermediary files/calculations?

Comment: Workarounds are possible: Saving a copy of your file with a different file name every so often. It's a bit cumbersome however. Another possibility within GIMP is to create a new layer from visible every so often, then continue editing., although no less cumbersome I'm afraid.  Adding all edits as individual layers is also possible, but again not really very practical if you need to do that for every single edit.

Comment: There's no macro recording in GIMP either.  There's something similar in Photoshop called Actions, but not every single function in Photoshop is necessarily actionable. It has its limitations, and is not the same as recording all the history. Actions in PS are usually recorded for steps you would repeat often.

Comment: @BillyKerr What about cropping with unchecked "delete cropped pixels" (i.e., "keep" cropped pixels): do these (kept pixels) "survive" a save-close-and-reopen document operation?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty yes. Everything in the XCF format is retained as editable except for history/undos.  But not other formats, such as PNG, JPEG, etc.  Make sure to save your work as XCF.  Use other formats for output files only.

Comment: In addition to all the comments above: in Gimp 2.10, by using layer groups and proper layer blend modes and composition modes, you can avoid some destructive operations, so you can later further edit/tweak the image without having to undo anything. And non-destructive editing will be generalized in Gimp 3.0.

Comment: Beginner's idea for a workaround of sorts: a) take a screenshot of "complicated" adjustments b) paste this screenshot as a new layer (and then hide or delete this layer when no longer needed).

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - There's need to use a screenshot. You can just create a new layer from visible. **Layer > New from Visible**. It's one of the workarounds I already mentioned.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah, but additionally I stashed a screenshot of the settings I chose. I'm far away from batch processing stuff; even implementing your suggestions isn't trivial for me; got some basic reading (e.g. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Color_Curves/) to do... if I pick up that file in a few weeks from now I will recall how to re-produce the mess I made :-)